# The Gang's all Here!

Tags: word

You see, Adam is very particular of who he befriends at school. See if you can figure out the pattern.

> Adam is friends with Nick but not Noah.
>
> Adam is friends with Benny but not Brent.
>
> Adam is friends with Liam but not Levi.
>
> Adam is friends with Gavin but not Glenn.

So, can you figure out another one of his friends?

---

<sup>Inspired by [DEEM's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=grandpa) Grandpa puzzles!</sup>

Comment: This kinda similar to one of the Grandpa puzzles :)

Comment: That's what I was sort of inspired by :D

Comment: I see, I just love these kinds of puzzles :D

Comment: Yeah me too, I like looking at the newest Grandpa editions :)

Comment: Actually, I think this has to do with ROT 13 (gur cbfvgvbaf bs gur ibpny yrggref, evtug?)

Comment: Hmmm, No hints here :)

Comment: Lol, I think that could be a yes :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My guess is

> The names Adam likes can be spelled with element symbols from the periodic table. Notice "Adam" sounds like "atom". He likes NiCK, BeNNY, LiAm, and GaVIn. But it doesn't look like there's any way to spell Noah, Brent, Levi, or Glenn with only chemical symbols.

So Adam probably also likes

> HArAmBe

Comment: I wish I had three more upvotes that I could spend on just one answer, namely, this one! Hahaha, that last line xD **Edit:** I have a friend called Adam who loves science. After looking at your answer, from now on, I am going to call him Rot13("Pneoba Nqnz") :D

Comment: I find this to be quite humerus. +1

Comment: +1 for Harambe :D

Comment: Great job!! This is correct :D   Oh and you even got the rot13(nqnz gb ngbz) hint

Answer (score 3):

This might not be right, but here goes:

> **A**dam is friends with **N**ick but not **N**oah.
>  The capital letters of of the first line spell 'Ann'. Ann is his other friend.

Comment: Hmm I don't think so. Then the others will read as ABB, AGG and ALL

Comment: @R.D that's what I thought. But ABB could be ABBY or ABIGAIL; AGG could be AGATHA and ALL could be ALI or ALICE or something.

Comment: Agatha and Alice seem like a stretch to me. Hmmm there must be something else

Comment: @R.D yes... maybe **Riley**'s answer reveals what that something else could be... :D

Comment: @user477343 Both Riley's answer and KevinL's comment seem to be hints.